# Quicksort with a twist in c++

Tags: c++, sorting

When sorting an array of objects some objects might swap places. This can by very expensive in terms of time and space, as each swap requires to copy an object.

In some cases sorting the entire array is not required. For example: Given an array of times for a marathon. The array should be sorted that the fastest 200 times are correctly sorted at the start of the array. Similarly one might be interested in the order of the 100 worst times. Important here is that the array apart from the top and the buttom does not have to be sorted.

The function that you should implement not only takes a pointer to the array of a template class and the size of that array as parameters. It also takes two further parameter front and end . The function will change the given array so that the first front elements are the smallest in the entire array and that these front elements are sorted. Similarly, the highest end elements are at the end of the array and also these end elements are sorted. Any other elements don't have to be sorted.

Example, for an array ["michael", "sam", "chris", "tom", "anna", "nick", "brian", "lisa"] and front =2 and end =3 
the array after calling the function might be ["anna", "brian", "michael", "lisa", "chris", "nick", "sam", "tom"] 
Note, it is important that first two names are "anna" and "brian", as well as the array finishes with "nick", "sam", "tom"

Finally the function will take two further parameters of type int which are passed by reference. When the function finishes these will contain the number of swaps and the number method calls during the run of the function.

The function declaration is
    template < class T> void quickSort(T * array,int size,
      int front, int end, int & calls, int & swaps) 
Your function should be based on the quicksort algorithm. Hence you will need to write an addition function which contains recursive calls. To count the number of swaps and calls you should use global variables.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Instead of just copying and pasting the text from the text book tell us what you don't understand about it.

Comment: Too bad this is homework.  In the real world, you'd just use `std::partial_sort` and/or `std::nth_element`.

Comment: After all of that, your only question is "Can anyone help me in this?".  That is NOT a valid question.  What have you done so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Make an attempt and post your code if you get stuck but don't ask to have it done for you.

Comment: The start of this is bogus. Who would sort an array of large objects instead of an array of pointers to large objects?

Comment: @Nathon: It's an exercise: he's being ask to "discover" the obvious strategy of sorting pointers. And if he understands what he is doing and why he'll really learn something.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like homework.  Rather than store the entire object into the array, consider just storing a pointer to the object.  Then the sort only moves the pointers.  It'll be fast.